# The return value of methods when adding a COM Reference generated proxy stub in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com, atl, stub

I have this method in my ATL project which exposes a COM object (snippet taken from my `*.idl` file):

```
[id(1)] HRESULT Create([in, string] CHAR* location, [out] CerberusErrorDetails* details);
```

After registering my object and adding a reference to it from my managed C# code, it generates the following proxy stub C# code for this method:

```
[DispId(1)]
void Create(string location, out CerberusErrorDetails details);
```

There are a few problems with this stub for me which I have been unable to sort out. Firstly, it does not return an `int` value (with respect to the returned `HRESULT`) in managed code to tell me what error has actually occurred. Secondly, the method will throw an exception instead of returning the error code. Is there a way to have the function return an `int` such that I can then parse the `details` object if it does not return `0`, or are there any alternatives to get the behavior I want? Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more details, feel free to ask and I'll update the question. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception because *that's the normal way to deal with errors in .NET*. The exception does expose an [`HResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property if you need to inspect it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Its too bad they automatically went with treating results the .NET way. In any case, the weird thing is if I wrap my call in a try-catch block, I get a `System.AccessViolationException`, otherwise I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`...so either way, my application still crashes. Why is this so frustrating?

Comment: I strongly suspect the number of people who are both writing the COM component and interoperating with it from .NET are vastly dwarfed by the number of people just *consuming* COM components from .NET. Forcing everyone to learn *both* error handling techniques would be cruel and unusual. If you want more help with this though, I think you'll have to create an MCVE.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I can't really create a full MCVE because the third party library I am calling into from inside of my COM object is not redistributable without the proper licensing. In a nutshell, my project is C# wrapper -> MSVC++ COM Object -> C wrapper -> 3rd party library in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to bypass the default exception translation behavior of the COM interop layer. However, you'll have to redefine your native COM interface and decorate all methods with the [`PreserveSig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("xxx-yyy-zzz")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface ICOMInterfaceImp
{
     [PreserveSig]
     int Create(string location, out CerberusErrorDetails details);
}
```

You can then use this interface in your client:

```
ICOMInterfaceImp obj = (ICOMInterfaceImp)new CoClassImpl();
```

As an alternative, you may also use the updated type library importer (tlbimp.exe) from [here](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/17579) and pass the `/PreserveSig` flag.